# Why do I have a Kubernetes api permission problem?

Tags: api, kubernetes, rbac

I have a python script that tries to scale a statefulset from inside a pod, but get a forbidden error from the API server. The following yml file shows my role and rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
Kind: Role
metadata:
  name: server-controller
  namespace: code-server
roles:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources:
      - statefulsets
    verbs: ["update", "patch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
Kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: server-controller
  namespace: code-server
subjects:
  -kind: ServiceAccount
   name: server-controller
   namespace: code-server
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name server-controller
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The following python code snippet shows my access to the API:

```
kubernetes.config.load_incluster_config()
app = kubernetes.client.AppsV1Api()
body = {"spec": {"replicas": 1}}
app.patch_namespaced_stateful_set_scale(
      name="jim",
      namespace="code-server",
      body=body)
```

I get the following error:

```
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache", 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Fri, 15 Oct 2021 15:25:24 GMT', 'Content-Length': '469'})
HTTP response Body: {
   "kind": "Status",
   "apiVersion": "v1"
   "metadata": {

    }
   "status": "Failure",
   "message": "statefulsets.apps \"jim\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:code-server:server-controller\" cannot patch resource \"statefulsets/scale\" in API group \"apps\" in the namespace \"code-server\"",
   "reason": "Forbidden",
   "details": {
     "name": "jim",
     "group": "apps",
     "kind": "statefulesets"
   }
   "code": 403
}
```

Comment: Hello @J.Ike In the provided configuration  for RoleBinding I see missed colon for `name server-controller` Is it only here or in cluster also? Can you check it?

Comment: Sorry, it just wasn't copied correctly. However, I found my problem. The "resources" field under role needed to be changed to "statefulsetsets/scale".

Comment: Fine! Could you describe your solution in the Answer?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change "statefulsets" to "statefulsets/scale" in the "resources" field under "role".